# Could WordPress Be Preventing Hidden Form Fields from being recognized?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have struggled with this issue for a majority of the day and I am really stumped.

I have this page called `preview.php` with the following code below. Values are being passed to this page from another page called `order.php`. This `preview.php` page allows a user to review his or her data input from `order.php`.

If correction is needed, the user returns to `order.php` to make his or her corrections. If everything looks fine, the user sends his or her orders to `process.php` to be processed. The information sent to `process.php` are hidden form fields.

For some reason that I am unable to figure out, `process.php` is not recognizing the hidden form field values.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

This gentle man @spencer7593 actually helped me out with this insert statement. However, each time I attempt to add a record, I get the following:

> Error: custname value cannot be null

This happens because the hidden form values are null and I can't figure out why.

**preview.php**

```
?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "DEBUG POST DATA: <pre>".print_r($_POST, 1)."</pre>";
if(isset($_POST['custname']))
$custname = $_POST['custname'];
if(isset($_POST['zip']))
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
if(isset($_POST['city']))
$city = $_POST['city'];
if(isset($_POST['email']))
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
$row2IDs = $_POST['row2IDs'];

echo $custname .'<br>';
echo $zip .'<br> <hr width=400 align=left>';


$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];

foreach ($rowIDs as $id) {
    $agentname = $_POST['agentname' . $id];
    $agentaddress = $_POST['agentaddress' . $id];
    $agentincome = $_POST['agentincome' . $id];

    echo 'Name:     '. $agentname . '<br />';
    echo 'Address:   '. $agentaddress . '<br />';
    echo 'agentincome:   '. $agentincome . '<br /><br>';
}

?>
<body>
<form action='process.php' method = 'POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='custname' value="<?php echo $custname; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='address' value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='city' value="<?php echo $city; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='zip' value="<?php echo $zip; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='agentname' value="<?php echo $agentname; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='agentaddress' value="<?php echo $agentaddress; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='agentincome' value="<?php echo $agentincome; ?>">
<input type="action" type="button" value="Return to data" onclick="history.go(-1);" /> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Submit your form" />
</form>
</body>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// Database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","myuser","mypwd","myDB");
if(!$conn) {
die('Problem in database connection: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Data insertion into database
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `myDB`.`myTable` ( `custname`'
     . ', `address`, `city`, `zip`, `email` )'
     . ' VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ?  )';

if( $sth = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql) ) {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sssss'
      ,$_POST["custname"]
      ,$_POST["address"]
      ,$_POST["city"]
      ,$_POST["zip"]
      ,$_POST["email"]

   );
   if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth) ) {
     echo '<h1>Thank you</h1> <br> Go back to the main page <a href="index.php");';
   } else {
      printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_stmt_error($sth));
   }
} else {
   printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error($conn));
}

?>
```

Comment: Side note, this appears invalid html `<input type="action" type="button" value="Return to data" onclick="history.go(-1);" />` It has two type attributes. Presumably you should be only wanting the `type="button"`

Comment: Also, your `foreach()` loop overwrites the assignments on every loop. Not sure if that is intended...

Comment: on the process page do `print_r($_POST);` to see what it's receiving from the other page.

Comment: @Rasclatt,

Thanks for your responses.

I did F12 to see what's going on and this is what I see:

`<input�type='hidden'�name='custname'�value="John Doe"="">`

This is why the screen is showing blank.

Do you know why that is  happening and how to resolve it?

I have never seen anything like this before.